# Shell sort worst case time complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, shell, time-complexity

I wanted to understand the worst case analysis by this code for shell sort. Can you guys please help me in finding out? The `while` loop will execute *`O(log n)`* times and `for` loops *`O(n)`* times; how does the complexity come out to be *`O(n^2)`* then? A complete answer would be appreciated; I've be stuck on this for a day.

```
int i, n = a.length, diff = n/2, interchange, temp;
while (diff > 0) 
{ 
  interchange=0;
  for (i = 0; i < n - diff; i++) 
  {
    if (a[i] > a[i + diff]) 
    { 
      temp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[i + diff];
      a[i + diff] = temp;
      interchange = 1;
    }
  }

  if (interchange == 0) 
  {
    diff = diff/2;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem duplicate. I went through that and there is difference in both code and query. Kindly unduplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are looking at is you are confusing the average case and the worst case. In an average case, the diff will update regularly and divide, causing the while loop to execute close to lgn times. However, you have the chance every loop that interchange becomes 1 due to data being swapped. If the data is sorted in the worst possible way, every loop will move data. This will cause the while loop to execute n times instead of lgn. With both the while loop and the for loop at o(n), you are looking at o(n^2)

Consider sorting an array of length 4. with numbers: 4, 3, 2, 1.

First loop, you find and switch 4 and 2, and 3 and 1. This makes your loop: 2, 1, 4, 3.

Next loop, nothing happens, interchange is 0, so it halves your diff.

Third Loop, you find and switch 2 and 1, and 4 and 3: 1, 2, 3, 4

Interchange is 1, diff is still 1, so you do another loop. Nothing happens, and diff becomes 0.5 exiting your loop.

In this case the while loop executed n times along with the for loop executing n times.

Comment: It's worth noting, that a shell sort uses an increment counter to compare only every Kth element. Since you are comparing EVERY element, it's more like a bubble sort than a shell sort. This is because your for loop is incrementing by 1. If you need help understanding shell sorting, this should be helpful: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheShellSort.html

Comment: I understood by example. But how did you simply arrive at this via code which took me whole day. Ì want to learn this art of arriving via seeing the code. Also with the same code, can you arrive at average and best case?

Comment: Sure i will look at it. But can you help me with computation method and how you arrived also best and avg case

Comment: The things you want to consider when approaching this kind of problem is that you can't assume the way you want the loop to work is the way it is necessarily going to work. We want this to run O(lgn) times, because we only actually do things on O(lgn) loops. However, since the loop in question is based on a variable that doesn't update every loop, we have to confirm that this behavior we expect actually happens. In this case it doesn't.

Comment: Best and avg case one please too

Comment: As far as best case, we need to assume the information is already sorted. In this case, every iteration of the for loop will not do anything, causing diff to get updated every loop. This causes the while loop to actually execute O(lgn) times.

Comment: As far as avg case. This is a whole lot harder to show in a simple way. Typically in an avg case you want to assume the most likely course of action. Unfortunately, due to this being closer to a bubble sort because of your for loop, the average case is also basically O(n^2). You'd need to find a way to not run the for loop again when the data is already sorted for the iteration. I'm not THAT familiar with shell sort, so you'd be best off looking at the shell sort write up that I sent. It seems like the average case for it is O(nlgn) at a precursory glance.

Comment: Correct about the best case at O(nlgn)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also help me out with basic learning capability towards calculating complexity by just seeing the code like what you and op did in minutes. What all things to look and what is the method. I would improve with your answer. Thanks a lot so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90052/discussion-between-s-cannon-and-icantcode).

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is not a shell sort. Shell sort works by performing a basic bubble sort multiple times. Each time, you consider just elements that have a gap of k elements between them. k is given by a decreasing sequence that ends with 1. Your sequence is n/2, n/4, n/8, ..., 1, which is fine. But you're not performing a bubble sort for each member of this sequence; you performing just one pass, which is not enough. The worst case complexity of O(n^2) is due to the bubble sort.

Note that in your case, since the sequence does not have a constant length, your worst case complexity would be O(n^2 * logn), if you fix the algorithm.

For more details about the algorithm, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) is your friend.

Later edit:

The corrected code is:

```
int i,n=a.length,diff=n/2,interchange,temp;
 while(diff>0) { 
 interchange=0;
 for(i=diff; i<n;i++) {
    temp=a[i];
    for (j = i; j >= gap && a[j-gap] > temp; j -= gap)
      a[j] = a[j-gap];  
    a[j]=temp;
  }
  diff=diff/2;
 }
```

Be aware that I didn't check it, so I might be wrong. Now, can you see the nested for loop that makes the complexity O(n^2)?

Comment: Can you help me to understand how you arrived by looking at my code. I just want to understand how you calculated it.

Comment: How you calculated O(n^2 * logn) for this code of mine. That is what i want to know. I have gone mad the whole day in understanding to calculate this. Thanks much

Comment: please answer the above queries. Much appreciated

Comment: Your code is wrong. You should have 2 nested for loops inside that while, not just one. Check the wikipedia link provided.

Comment: Can you correct and explain the above queries in 1 answer

Comment: can you correct my code and point to a proper implementation in java for shell sort